# Конкатенация классов (BEM) в Pug (ex-Jade)?

Tags: jade, pug, бэм

Все привет, вопрос такой. Как правильно наследовать класс от родительского класса как в `Sass`:

`.b1_form
     .b1_form-title Заголовок`

Чтобы во втором классе не писать родительский, а что-то типа `&-title` (как в CSS-препроцессорах)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В самом `Pug` нет изначально конкатенации классов, однако она легко добавляется с набором миксинов [Bemto](https://github.com/kizu/bemto).

После добавления миксинов к вашему шаблону, данный синтаксис:

```
+b.block1
  +e.element1 Foo
  +b.block2
    +e.A(href="#bar").element Bar
  +e.element2 Baz
```

Будет компилироваться в такой `HTML`:

```
<div class="block1">
  <div class="block1__element1">
    Foo
  </div>
  <div class="block2">
    <a class="block2__element" href="#bar">Bar</a>
  </div>
  <div class="block1__element2">
    Baz
  </div>
</div>
```